# Split a movie file into audio and video Psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, audio, split, video-processing, psychtoolbox

I am working on a project where I have to split a movie file into its basic audio and video parts first. After googling and through documentation and psychdemos in psychtoolbox, I am unable to find even a clue to this issue. 
Is there any function in psychtoolbox to split a movie clip like .mpeg or .mov or .avi or .flv into its audio and video parts ?
Please help.
Thanks a lot for your consideration.

Comment: Please add an answer so others who have the same question can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is key to realize that pyschtoolbox is well simply a toolbox. There is a host of other built in MATLAB functions that you can use along with pyschtoolbox.

It looks like even in MATLAB, doing this is a pain in the a$$, but I did find this untested by me FEX entry. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028-mmread

It looks like it should be able to do what you want and it does not depend on purchasing other toolboxes, etc.

By the way, is this a project from elance.com?

Comment: This is my final year project.

Comment: Ok, well PLEASE post your answer then so other people can benefit in the future.